# Is it possible to recreate a select from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the values of an existing select from Javascript, and after a while looking for in internet I am not sure that is possible.

I have this piece of code:

```
function clickPic(pic_select, choosen, opt){
    //Here I change the border of a selected image
    if (opt!=0){
    pic_select.style.border = "3px solid blue";
    }else{pic_select.style.border = "3px solid red";}
    // here I send the variable (it's a number) which I want to change the values of the select.
    var option_master = opt; 
    cambiarSelect(option_master);   
}

    function cambiarSelect(num){
       //here num is 4 or 6 or 12, depending
       //this is the select itself
        var people = document.getElementById('people');
       //I guess here I reset the select
        people.options.length=0;

        for(var i=1;i<=num.length;i++){
            //here I want to change the values of the select with the same number than num, because thats the value I'm interested to select later
            people.options[i]=new Option(i);
        }
    }
```

I'm sorry for my way of programming but it's been a long time since I don't touch a keyboard, but I kind of remember it was possible some how

Comment: You can do it. Justo create the elements with strings and then use innerHTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function cambiarSelect(num) {
  //here num is 4 or 6 or 12, depending
  //this is the select itself
  var people = document.getElementById('people');
  //I guess here I reset the select
  
  people.innerHTML = ''; //Clean your select

  for (var j = 1; j <= num; j++) {
    //here I want to change the values of the select with the same number than num, because thats the value I'm interested to select later
    people.add(new Option(j, j));
  }
}

cambiarSelect(6);
```

```html
<select id='people'>
<option>Temporary</option>
<option>Temporary2</option>
<option>Temporary3</option>
</select>
```

## Resource

- [`Option()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option)
- [`HTMLSelectElement.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)

Comment: Ele! You're a machine man!! Solved!! I knew it when I saw your code, it's been a long time since I don't programm.